# How can I create an instance of a class with resolve from inside my method using Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I have been using Unity to create classes with constructor injection like this:

```
 public class ProductsController : BaseController
    {
        public ProductsController(
            IService<Account> accountService,
            IService<Product> productService)
        {
            _account = accountService;
            _product = productService;
        }
```

**Bootstrapper:**

```
private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.FromConfigurationSetting("DEV_DataConnectionString");
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<   IService<Account>, AccountService   >();
            container.RegisterType<   IService<Product>, ProductService   >();
            container.RegisterType<IAzureTable<Product>, AzureTable<Product>>(new InjectionConstructor(storageAccount, "TestProducts"));
            return container;
        }
```

Now I need to create an instance of a service instance "on the fly" from within my method. Something like this:

```
    public void Update(string serviceClassName) {

        var serviceClass = new container.Resolve<IService<Product>>();
```

But there are some things I don't understand.

- First of all do I need to create a new container? I assume I need to reference the container I already created but I can't find any reference on how to do that.
- Second here I have hardcoded Product but what I need is to be able to pass in the word "Product" as a parameter and then have it constructed.

How can I create my class ?

**Update**

Not tested yet but I believe the solution for naming of my class may require me to register my class as follows:

```
container.RegisterType<   IService<Product>, ProductService   >("productService");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of generics rather than using strings:

```
public void Update<T>(T item) {
    var serviceClass = container.Resolve<IService<T>>();
    serviceClass.DoSomething();
}
```

Usage:

```
Update(someProduct); 
// generic type is inferred. Same as - Update<Product>(someProduct)
```

I believe you can get a reference to your container by adding a constructor dependency of type `IUnityContainer` - see [Can a unity container pass a reference of itself as a constructor parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827756/can-a-unity-container-pass-a-reference-of-itself-as-a-constructor-parameter)

Comment: Thanks Ben. I will look into this now.

Comment: Still looking into this. The link you gave does tell me I can add a constructor dependency but then there's part of that page saying I don't need to add one. Doesn't seem clear to me yet.

Comment: If you have access to an object constructed by your container (i.e. via constructor injection) then you can access its `.Container` property. In either case I think the cleaner approach is to inject your container.

Comment: The problem is the word Product or Package or Content is coming into my update function from javascript. So there's no class being passed around rather it's just a string that has a name that's the same as the class.

Comment: So you have some kind of generic form and want to handle it with a single action method? Why not have an action method for each type of class - doing it in a generic fashion adds a lot of (unnecessary complexity).

Answer (score 0):

Make a global public static class, and add a public static unitycontainer property to it. Then you can use it globally.

For the class creation... you can use reflection like this for resolving :

```
public static class MyContainer
{
    public static UnityContainer Container { get; set; }
}

class ServiceClass<T>
{}

class ReturnClass
{}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }

    ReturnClass DoResolve(string name)
    {
        Type type = typeof (UnityContainer);
        MethodInfo genericMethod = type.GetMethod("Resolve").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(ServiceClass<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[]{Type.GetType(name)}));
        object invoke = genericMethod.Invoke(MyContainer.Container,null);
        return (ReturnClass) invoke;
    }
}
```

And after this you can just call this DoResolve()...

I hope I helped in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use a magic string to dispatch updates to a service? If you know the string on the client side you could just as well call the appropriate service method *UpdateProduct(...)*, *UpdateCustomer(...)*. And then you would not need any guesswork on the service side.